# How to read Protected data from Facebook ads API / PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am getting a protected object returned from the API call to Facebook Ads.

I am making a call with

```
$campaigns = $account->getAdCampaigns($fields, $params);
```

and the account class doesn't have any method for reading the protected data.

```
FacebookAds\Cursor Object
(
    [response:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Response Object
        (
            [content:protected] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => <campaign_name>
                                    [objective] => WEBSITE_CLICKS
                                    [id] => <campaign_id>
                                )

                )

        )
```

Do I need to create this function. Seems strange the SDK wouldn't have this functionality already.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? We didn't consider that you would ever need to read this. If you're trying to read the objects in a cursor, you can use the getObjects() which will give you all of the campaigns in this case. The Response object is only used to know how to traverse the full set of pages.

Comment: @PaulBain - Trying to access campaign (adcampaign_group)  data (specifically ID, NAME,OBJECTIVE, STATUS) by passing in the <ad_account_id>. The only other way I can find how to do it is by passing in each <campaign_id> individually which just causes me to reach my rate limit very quickly. I am really struggling to find any other way to do this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
use FacebookAds\Api;

Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);

use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CampaignFields;


 $account = new AdAccount('act_'.$act_id);

 $objects = $account->getCampaigns(array(
 CampaignFields::NAME,
 CampaignFields::ID,
 CampaignFields::STATUS,

 ));

 $objects->setUseImplicitFetch(true); // set this before loop
 foreach ($objects as $object) {
 if($object->{CampaignFields::STATUS }=='ACTIVE'){

    $campaign_id= $object->{CampaignFields::ID};
    $name= $object->{CampaignFields::NAME};
    $status = $object->{CampaignFields::STATUS};
    $values[] = array(
    'campaign_id' => $campaign_id,
    'name' => $name,
    'status' => $status,

   );
    }
  }
 echo json_encode($values);
```